# How to redirect 404 to start page?

Tags: firebase, http-status-code-404, firebase-hosting

I just started to host a web application on firebase.
the automatic setup with the `firebase cli` (firebase-tools) created a `404.html` file in my public folder.

but i don't want to see a custom 404 error page nor the default one from firebase.
I would like to redirect all 404 to the startpage, so that the app will get initialised anyway. (my local setup with `webpack-dev-server` is just working fine)

a workaround is just to put the same content from `index.html` into the `404.html`. But this leads into doubled maintenance..

i found some information about redirect configuration here https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites.
but a redirect for 404 error types isn't possible.
using a `.htaccess` file isn't possible.

am i missing the right location to change this behaviour whether in my `firebase.json` file or in the https://console.firebase.google.com/??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you, I've never done stuff with `.htaccess`, but in my case I've always fixed it this way:

You can include a wildcard route as the last route in the rewrites section of your `firebase.json` file, so any previously unclaimed routes will match:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    // route info here
  },
  {
    // another route
  },
  {
    // If it makes it here, it didn't match any previous routing
    // Match all routes that get to this point and send them to the home page.
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: yes it's the rewrites thingy! https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to have original/non-existent url left (eg. https://example.com/asdf) you can modify 404.html source and replace it with js redirect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page Not Found</title>
    <script>
      window.location.href = "/";
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the firebaes.json You just need to update the destination's field to "404.html" if you want it to redirect to 404 when it does not match any route of your application. Then run `firebase deploy` command to see the changes